# AngularJS Based Loading Spinner & Overlay

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a loading spinner which is working fine when I include the spinner in controller, I am using the following http://angularscript.com/demo/angularjs-based-loading-spinner-overlay/

This is my controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, appService) {

var employeesList = appService.GetEmployess();
$scope.spinner = {
    active: true
};
employeesList.then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.Employees = response.data;
    $scope.spinner = {
        active: false
    };
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
});
```

This is how it is loading on initial load
[image]

When I remove `$scope.spinner` inside success call back this is how it is loading

```
var employeesList = appService.GetEmployess();
$scope.spinner = {
    active: true
};
employeesList.then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.Employees = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
});
```

[image]

What I need is I would like to show the loading panel on the center screen, how can I achieve that or is there any other loading panel. My html is as follows

```
<body ng-controller="EmployeeController">
    <treasure-overlay-spinner active='spinner.active'>
        <table tr-ng-grid='' items='Employees' page-items="10"></table>
    </treasure-overlay-spinner>
</body>
```

Comment: it's not really clear what your issue is here.

Comment: Is there a way to show the loading panel as per second image

Comment: where have you placed your spinner control in the html? any code of that will be helpful

Comment: you start off saying that you are "developing a loading spinner" then proceed to show code for some unknown module developed by someone else, and ask if there is any other you could use....  You aren't showing any HTML at all, so it's not really obvious what would be necessary to achieve the result you are asking about.

Comment: updated Jayakrishnan Gounder

Comment: Do you want the loading wheel in the center? Maybe you can show a modal with the spinning wheel and then close modal on success.  Another option would be to hide everything and show a div in the center of the page with the wheel.